# How to install another Linux distro?

Tags: linux, partitioning, linux-distributions

I started with a clean HDD.  Partitioned as follows...4GB for Swap, 1 10GB EXT4 partition mounted as /, another 50GB EXT4 partition mounted as /home.

Installed Mint.

Now I am curious to try Mageia Linux.

Where would I install it?  Do I need another '/' partition?

I haven't done much with Mint, so I don't have any reservations about wiping everything out and starting over.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to start the installation for new Linux.

swap and /home can be used (just check that flag format is not set on, when you will do partitioning).

Regarding the / , just create during the installation another 10gb or more partition and choose it as root.

Another question is the boot loader, check if your previous linux is using the same grub1 or grub2 version otherwise one of the Linux installs will not load.

Comment: The part about the boot loader isn't necessarily true, the version is pretty irrelevant.  If they do not install a new grub, then they can boot into mint and run `sudo update-grub`, which runs a detection for other OS's.  If they do install something else, it should run a similar hook and detect the other OS's.  That's true of the Grub loader (v1.97/2) and SysLinux.

Comment: sorry I was thinking that GRUB2 (1.97) over GRUB1 (0.97) will do chain load but, other way arround GRUB1 over GRUB2 will brake mbr and only last installed system will boot.

Comment: In which case you just add the lines to boot the other system in `menu.lst` (I may be forgetting the exact file), easy to get it working either way. But you're right, it would default to last installed. Though I wouldn't call that "breaking MBR".

Comment: yeah, sorry also calling it "breaking MBR" is wrong.